# Java - Divide Plan into sections

Tags: java, geometry, point, plane

Given a point with `x`, `y` coordinates, I would like to understand in which sector are the points near it.

Check this image:

[image]

My Point is like this:

```
public class Node {

    public final int id;
    public final double coordinates[];
    public ArrayList<Node> candidateList;

    public Node(int id,double... values){
        this.id=id;
        this.coordinates=values;
    }

    public int distance(Node other){
        double result = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x<this.coordinates.length;x++){
            result+=(this.coordinates[x]-other.coordinates[x])*(this.coordinates[x]-other.coordinates[x]); //TODO time difference with pow

        }
        return (int) Math.round(Math.sqrt((result)));
    }
}
```

Comment: How you are defining sectors in your project? Are sectors bounded by certain coordinates?

Comment: I asked how to divide in sectors only to understand the criterions to do it: in the end, I would like (for each Node) to parse every other Node existing and to see which one is the Nearest one in a precise definite Sector. In the end, I want to have an ArrayList<Node> with 16 Node (or less) (16 sectors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You picture shows 8 sectors, and you can find sector number with three simple conditions (x and y are coordinates relative to center):

```
x < 0
y < 0
abs(x) < abs(y)
```

These three conditions give three bits of information to define `2^3=8` possible states (sector number). So you just have to make a table to match every combinations of condition results to the sector number. For example:

```
0 0 1 => your sector 1   //x positive, y positive, abs(y)>abs(x)
0 1 0 => your sector 3
```

If you want more sectors, it would simpler to use angle-based approach. For example, for 16 sectors:

```
//note reverse argument order due to your sector numbering
angle = atan2(x, y)  
if angle < 0 then 
  angle = angle + 2 * Pi
sector = 1  + Floor(angle * 8.0 / Pi)
```

Comment: Nice! I just added the relativity (Xcenter and Ycenter), i hope it's right.

Still, i wanted to reach 16 sectors... any idea about that?

Comment: How these 16 sectors are defined? 8 sectors - 45 degrees each. 16 sectors -  22.5 degrees each?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, that was the idea